# Nested GetElementsByClassName returns undefined error inside of window.onload function

Tags: javascript

I have a table on my page and it looks something like this:

```
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Product description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <tr style="height: 50px;">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mug</td>
        <td>Perfect for drinking stuff</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td><a href="/products/detail?id=1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    etc....

</body>
```

I'm trying to write some javascript code to access the 'a' tag and the href attribute. **I can't give it an id to easily access it** so I am trying to access it via the following:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
console.log(btn.href);
```

However, I get the following error: btn is undefined.

If I try to print out the tbody element it is returning an object so I'm not sure why this isn't working for its child tag.

*I should note that this JavaScript is being executed in the window.onload function.*

Comment: There is a " hanging quote after <thead">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case is better to use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("tbody a")[0];
console.log(btn.href);
```

## Example:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("tbody a")[0];
console.log(btn.href);
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Product description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr style="height: 50px;">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mug</td>
        <td>Perfect for drinking stuff</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td><a href="/products/detail?id=1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```